# iOS 15.4 - SwiftUI + CarPlay - State not updating

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, carplay

It seems that with the update of **iOS 15.4** (March 14th, 2022) the state updating (SwiftUI) in a CarPlay app has been broken.

I have simplified my code to the example below. Please note this *was working* in iOS+CarPlay 15.3. This also works on an *iOS (only) app* running 15.4.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var test: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Seconds elapsed: \(self.test)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
                self.test += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example screenshot]

I can conclude that the state is not updated in a SwiftUI CarPlay app. Is there any new way of updating the state? I can't seem to pinpoint anything I might have missed. Maybe the CarPlay integration simply isn't fully supported yet using SwiftUI.
I had also reworked the code to use the menu button on top to increment `self.test`. This also does not have any effect.

**Configuration info**

CarPlay app is set up using the Info.plist.

```
Application Scene Manifest
> Scene Configuration
>> CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication (Array)
>>> Item 0
>>>> UISceneDelegateClassName = $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).AppDelegate
>>>> UISceneConfigurationName = Default Configuration
```

I listen for `CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate` in my `AppDelegate` and submit the appropriate template accordingly. I then bind a `UIHostingController` to the `CPWindow`'s `rootViewController` property.

I'd love to have some insights in what can cause this lack of updating the state. Not sure what I'm missing here. Thank you so much for your effort and response.

Comment: Did you tried with device and car ?

Comment: Yes. Tried both on the device and in an actual car (live environment). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Can you show the code in app delegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this issue is now magically resolved in the latest beta software. (iOS 16 beta 1)

No extra code added or changed.

Comment: How did you manage to display SwiftUI view on CarPlay ?

Comment: The same code as displayed above. This now works. Simply put the code in and make sure you set up the Info.plist as described. This way, your app knows it has a CarPlay screen. Use a `UIHostingController` and submit your SwiftUI view to it as root.

Comment: I’m running into this problem now with iOS 17.3. Is this still working for you @Ramon?

Comment: Hi @guido, yes, this (luckily) still seems to work on my end. Is it broken w/ 17.3? I did not update my Xcode yet, though.

Comment: Hi @Ramon. This is my first app update with a swiftUI view on the CarPlay screen (a speed indicator). The rest of the view (the map itself) it wrapped in a hostingviewcontroller and updates fine. The SwiftUI view does not. At least not on all CarPlay systems. On some it updates like every 5 seconds. On others it doesn’t update at all. It’s one of this hard to reproduce and diagnose problems. During beta test with 100+ tester (from iOS16 to iOS 17.2) this problem was never reported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted the app for review with SwiftUI in CarPlay? was it approved?

As per Apple documentation you are supposed to use only templates allowed by your app entitlement: [CarPlay programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/carplay/documentation/CarPlay-App-Programming-Guide.pdf)

Comment: This was simply a test to see if SwiftUI would work in CarPlay. The app is supposed to be a navigation app, where the centered label in my screenshot is replaced with a map. The app was approved for beta testing (at the time; iOS 14), but I had removed all the clutter in the project (e.g. map) with iOS 15 and changed the project to simply update a label to debug. Did not work as the label was static (no change), but iOS 16 magically updates the SwiftUI label again, counting up the seconds elapsed.