# Adding CarPlay to a SwiftUI lifecycle app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, carplay

What is the recommended way to integrate CarPlay into an app which uses a SwiftUI lifecycle ?

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

How do I use the `CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate` here ?

Comment: Depending on what you ask : CarPlay has its own delegate and templates (aka User Interface view, buttons, list ) . You define initial delegate  from the info file.

Comment: Check for [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/displaying_content_in_carplay)

Comment: @PtitXav your link describes the process for the Scene Delegate lifecycle which is a typical UIKIt one. If you start a project with SwiftUI you have the struct which inherits from App, there is no Scene Delegate

Comment: Check for [thsi}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71524945/ios-15-4-swiftui-carplay-state-not-updating/72658942?noredirect=1#comment128824523_72658942) : it uses UIHostingController

Comment: @PtitXav but this is not an App lifecycle. He uses AppDelegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a custom app delegate and/or scene delegate (you might need it eventually for stuff like push notifications) it should be enough to let your app know via the info.plist. You need a scene delegate for the CarPlay scene and add the following to your info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>TemplateSceneConfiguration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>AppFeature.CarPlaySceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The value for `UISceneConfigurationName` is handed to you in the scene delegate's `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` `session.configuration.name`.
The value for `UISceneDelegateClassName` has to match your CarPlay scene delegate's Type name. Note that if you encapsulate your CarPlay code in a package/framework you need to prefix the delegate's name with the module name (in this case `AppFeature`). If the delegate is in your app target just use `CarPlaySceneDelegate`.

An excerpt of the scene delegate might look like this:

```
class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
  let templateManager = TemplateManager() // see Apple's sample code

  func templateApplicationScene(_: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    templateManager.connect(interfaceController)
  }

  func templateApplicationScene(_: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didDisconnectInterfaceController _: CPInterfaceController) {
    templateManager.disconnect()
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I still get "Application does not implement CarPlay template application lifecycle methods in its scene delegate"

Answer (score 2):

I had a hell of a time with this, but finally got it working. First, add a `UIApplicationSceneManifest` to your plist. Note that `UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes` need not be true. It's really intended for macOS/Catalyst apps that support multiple windows. But a CarPlay scene isn't another `window` in this sense.

```
<plist>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarPlaySceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>CarPlay Configuration</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then your CarPlay scene delegate looks like this (note the class name matches the value of `UISceneDelegateClassName` from your plist)

```
import CarPlay

class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
    var interfaceController: CPInterfaceController?

    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
                                  didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = interfaceController

        let carPlayUI = ...  // CPTabBarTemplate, CPListTemplate, CPGridTemplate, etc

        interfaceController.setRootTemplate(carPlayUI, animated: true) { success, error in
            // optional completion handler once CarPlay UI is displayed
        }
    }

    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
                                  didDisconnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController,
                                  from window: CPWindow) {
        self.interfaceController = nil
    }
}
```